# Python urllib module TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.4, urllib

I'm trying to get into CTF's and I found a cool website ment to practice some web based CTF skills called ctf.slothparadise.com. I've managed to get 4 of the Flags but two of them are giving me the finger and sadly I've had to dust off the good Ol' Python skills.

```
import urllib.error
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib
import sys

while True:
        about_page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://ctf.slothparadise.com/about.php").read()
        if "KEY" in about_page:
            print(about_page)
            sys.exit(0)
```

ctf.slothpython.com/about.php is the page I'm programming for and it spits out the key in the source code every 1000 visitors. Instead of being a moron and refreshing it till 1000 I wrote that code in hopes it would keep opening the page until the phrase "KEY" appeared in the pages source code.

I'm getting this: (TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface)

From what I know about TypeErrors I'm guessing that I may have "KEY" in the wrong format perhaps? I'm not really sure, I also may not even be using the right modules but the old urllib2 module I would typically use for this got split up into different modules so I'm learning as I go with these new modules.

Any help is appreciated in fixing this issue, also if my interpretaion of TypeErrors is wrong feel free to correct me.

Comment: Apparently, `urlopen` returns the content of the page already, not a file-like object one can `read`.

Comment: Unless you really need to do otherwise, use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

The object returned by urlopen().read() [acts like a context manager](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request).

You are not using it correctly.

Try something like that:

```
import urllib.request
while True:
    with urllib.request.urlopen('http://ctf.slothparadise.com/about.php') as response:
        html = response.read()
        if b"KEY" in html:
            print(html)
            sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`urllib.request.urlopen` returns an `http.client.HTTPResponse` object and that object's `read` returns an encoded `bytes` object. How to decode may be in the returned http header, or in your case, embedded in an html `meta` tag. You likely don't want to parse the html for this particular test, so just look for the `bytes` object `b'KEY'`.

I don't know what you want to do with the data next, but if you want it to print nicely or scan the html, then you will have to do some parsing.

```
import urllib.error
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import urllib
import sys

while True:
        about_page = urllib.request.urlopen("http://ctf.slothparadise.com/about.php").read()
        if b"KEY" in about_page:
            print(about_page)
            sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make about_page a string with

`about_page=str(urllib.request.urlopen("http://ctf.slothparadise.com/about.php").read())`

This should make your code work. Hope this helps!!